# jQuery - Set Form's attribute to true on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

Hope someone can help me on this as I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have checked different posts but I cannot find anything different of what I'm already trying.

My model has an attribute:
`private boolean thisShouldBeTrue;`

The value of this should dynamically change depending on user's actions on the screen.
My form contains a hidden input to retrieve this value:

`<form:input path="thisShouldBeTrue" type="hidden" id="retrievedValue" />`

Different javascript functions show this working since I retrieved different values on submission when the user makes some action to trigger those scripts.

However, I cannot set this to true on page load (this is the value that should be sent by default if user take no other action).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#retrievedValue').val("true");
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should use `#` when use id with jquery as `$('#retrievedValue').val("true");`

Comment: Typo. `$('retrievedValue')` -> `$('#retrievedValue')` Also double check that the `form:input` control renders the `id` attribute exactly as you've set it in the template

Comment: Sorry, typo when posting the question. I have the # in my code.
I have a onClick function with the exact same line and is correctly setting the value when called.
For some reason, not working on ready function

Comment: In that case check the DOM as I mentioned before to ensure the `id` in the output matches what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `#` for selecting html element with id using jquery, see below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#retrievedValue').val("true");
});
```

Comment: Questions like this, where the issue is a simple typo, should just be closed as such.

Comment: It uses the semantics, not the syntax. But it does not support all xpath queries. Most of the Xpath structure is just simplified internally for easier development. Like accessing id and other queries.

Comment: Sorry, typo when posting the question. I have the # in my code. Edited the question

Comment: then your code should work provided that id is unique through out the DOM

Answer (score 0):

JQuery uses the Xpath semantics to identify elements in the DOM. To access an element through an ID, in this case retrievedValue, you can access it by `$("#<id>")`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#retrievedValue').val("true");
    });
```

Comment: Questions like this, where the issue is a simple typo, should just be closed as such.`

Comment: Also note that jQuery does not use XPath semantics at all. XPath syntax is entirely different

Comment: Sorry, typo when posting the question. I have the # in my code. Edited the question